# Personalized Email Message per Mailing List Recipient

Tags: phpmailer, mailing-list

I am using PHPmailer to send emails (newsletters) one by one to around 1000 contacts.  The problem is that my web host provider blacklists my account and insists that I use a mailing list (containing all contacts) instead of sending out emails one by one.

AFAIK the problem with mailing lists is that the emails sent is the same for everyone, which prevents you from personalizing each message. Aside from not being able to include personal info such as the contact's name and product preferences, you also cannot include a contact's unique id, which you use for unsubscribing and for tracking responses to links/offers/ads.

So my question is, what is the industry standard/accepted way/pattern of sending bulk emails? Is it by sending out individually, or by using mailing list?  If it's the latter, can you customize the email for each person in the mailing list?

Up to this point, I can only run PHPmailer from my web host provider and chose not to use third-party services such as MailChimp.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, email lists will only give you identical messages to all recipients. The standard for personalized batches is to use a [Message Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909791/asynchronous-processing-or-message-queues-in-php-cakephp)